# Sending data from Android to Simblee BLE not returning anything

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, simblee

Below is the sketch of my Simblee  :

```
#include <SimbleeBLE.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Waiting for connection...");
  SimbleeBLE.deviceName = "Simblee";
  SimbleeBLE.advertisementData = "data";
//  SimbleeBLE.customUUID = "2220";
  SimbleeBLE.advertisementInterval = MILLISECONDS(300);
  SimbleeBLE.txPowerLevel = -20;  // (-20dbM to +4 dBm)
  SimbleeBLE.begin();
}

void loop() {

}

void SimbleeBLE_onConnect()
{
  Serial.println("Simblee Connected");
}

void SimbleeBLE_onDisconnect()
{
  Serial.println("Simblee Disconnected");
}

void SimbleeBLE_onReceive(byte *data, int len)
{
  Serial.println("Data received");
  SimbleeBLE.send(1);
  printf("%s\n", data);
}

void serialEvent() 
{
   Serial.println("Serial event");
}
```

I can easily connect and read data from it, bit writing to it doesn't work from my app. SimbleeBLE_onReceive is never being called.

It actually never is called even when using third party BLE apps like nRF Connect and BLE Terminal.

So I'm suspecting that the issue is with my arduino Sketch and not related to the android code.

The android code is returning GATT_ERROR 133 when trying to write.

Is anything missing from this code ? Strangely I can't find any example online where we're simply sending data to Simblee (without using SimlbeeMobile)

Thanks,

Comment: GATT_ERROR 133 means your device is disconnected from ble

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan yes it can be, But I'm sure the issue is from the simblee part, not the mobile app part, and this is what i need to fix

Comment: Seems the peripheral is not correctly setup. Try to find manuals or sample code. You can also use Android's hci log or an air sniffer to see what's really going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your onReceive signature to:

```
void SimbleeBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len)
```

Comment: Thank you that was the issue!

Comment: I'd also advice you to check out the reference: https://www.simblee.com/Simblee%20Functions%20Reference%20V1.0.pdf it's the one i'm using :)

Comment: do you have any idea about this question ?

Whitebear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607479/best-practice-to-stream-data-in-realtime-from-android-to-bluetooth

Thanks